# element positioned to the right overlaps table

Tags: html, css

I have html code:

```
<div id="right">right</div>
<table>
    <tr><td>row</td></tr>
</table>
```

with css:

```
#right
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

and as a result both table and div start at the top of the page but I want table to start below the div. What can I do about it?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrkno49u/

Comment: Don't use `position:absolute`? Then put the div after the table in the HTML where it belongs.

Comment: [Yep, drop it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036170/element-positioned-to-the-right-overlaps-table#30036170)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **absolute positioning** so it took the div out of the flow. Hence for table the div doesn't exist.
To achieve what you want : You can set **position:relative;** for div & move the box accordingly to the right by setting it's left property in css.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a float instead of absolute positioning, and then clear the float for the table:

```
#right
{
    float:right;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
}
table {
    clear: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrkno49u/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do nothing more. Just remove `position: absolute; right: 0px;` from `#right`

```css
#right
{
 border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">right</div>
<table>
    <tr><td>row</td></tr>
</table>
```

Check Your [updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jrkno49u/3/)